# Difference in $http response and Api response [AngularJs]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http

I have an issue on my application when I get an API request from members belongs to a particulary group.

```
GET /api/organizations/1234/members?group=4321
```

If I start my navigation with this request, I have the right members but if I navigate in other page with other groupe before, the $http response is full of parasite members whereas the response form API is right *(check from network tab in Chrome developper tools)*.

I think about some cache but I can not find it ! For info, I use [jsData](http://www.js-data.io/) for mounting my data but it's not seems to be the problem.

Here the code of my function to send Api Request :

```
var loadGroupMembers = function() {
 return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
   var callParams = {
     organizationId: $stateParams.OrganizationId,
     groupId: $stateParams.groupId
   };

   sendApiCall('groupMembers', 'get', callParams)
     .success(function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
    });
 });
};

var sendApiCall = function(requestId, method, params, data, queryStringParams) {
  params = params || {};
  data = data || {};

  var apiCallConfig = {
    params: config.params,
    method: config.method,
    url: "/api/organizations/1234/members?group=4321",
    data: data,
    cache : false
  };

  $rootScope.fn.setHistory($state.current.name, 'apiCall', 'sendManualApiCall:' + requestId);
  return $http(apiCallConfig);
};
```

Please tell me if you have questions or need more details.
Thanks for your help ! :)

*Edit : I add the function that call sendApiCall and I made a little apiary to show you how the data from api are : http://private-52326-groupmember.apiary-mock.com/organization/1234/members?group=4321*

Comment: Can you provide more informations about on how you use it and add some details on parameters passed to your function ? A jsbin/plunker can be a good start too

Comment: @Payou Thanks for your answer, I add some details in my post, I don't know if it's enough but I see no other code which directly impact this api call. And this apiCall works perfeclty for a lot of others requests, that's strange ...

Comment: I still think a jsbin/plunker with how you run your code could help a lot more. But some strange things I notice : sendApiCall never use method/params arguments because config.params/method are always used ! config is defined somewhere ? Other thing, where you use loadGroupMembers method? I can't do more without runnable code... Hope this can already help you a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kind of link with Jsdata and an interceptor created by an other developer. For each api request, the interceptor add some data on the response with the same type ... So the issue is closed.
Thanks for your help anyway :)